# Retrieve security permissions for a Security Group from Active Directory

Tags: c#, permissions, active-directory

I am trying to create a function where I input a *Security Group* name and return a list of the security permissions.

How do I get a list of security permissions like `read`, `write`, `full control` etc. for a *Security Group* such as `Domain Controllers`, `Domain Guests`, etc. from Active Directory using C#?

Answer (score 2):

You need to check the path of the LDAP connection that you are making to communicate with the Active Directory server.

For example:

```
 DirectoryEntry rootDSE = null;
  rootDSE = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://OU=" + department + ",OU=Users,OU=" + ou + ",dc=corp,dc=local", username, password);
```

Now in that case I need only groups that exist in **Department → Users → OU → DC**

Same as in your case. You can define on which OU your security group exist.

After that I can fetch a group like this:

```
DirectorySearcher ouSearch = new DirectorySearcher(rootDSE);
ouSearch.PageSize = 1001;
ouSearch.Filter = "(objectClass=group)";
ouSearch.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
ouSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("name");
SearchResultCollection allOUS = ouSearch.FindAll();
foreach (SearchResult oneResult in allOUS)
{
     dt.Rows.Add(oneResult.Properties["name"][0].ToString());
}
rootDSE.Dispose();
```

**Now in case of permissions**

Permissions are stored on the individual file system items, e.g. files and/or directories - or other objects (like registry keys, etc.). When you have an AD group or user account, you can read its SID (Security Identifier) property - that SID will show up in ACLs (Access Control Lists) all over Windows - but from the user or group, there's no mechanism to get all permissions it might have anywhere in the machine/server.

Permissions for files and directories can e.g. be retrieved using the .GetAccessControl() method on the FileInfo and DirectoryInfo classes:

```
FileInfo info = new FileInfo(@"D:\test.txt");
FileSecurity fs = info.GetAccessControl();

DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\test\");
DirectorySecurity ds = dir.GetAccessControl();
```

I hope this is what you are looking for!

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply.The above code gives list of groups in the Active Directory, but i am looking for the code snippet where i can give group (Eg:"Domain Controller") as a input to the function of the C# , which retrieves all the security Permission of the group(Fg:Domain Controller) like Read , Write,Create Childs etc., permissions

Comment: Have you read this paragraph:-**Now In Case of Permissions.**?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. You mean to tell that the security TAB UI Permission details of the Security groups(EG:DOmain Controller")in the Active Directory cannot be get programmatically? If read/Write of Security Tab UI Permissions could be set programmatically, Is getting the All Permission details is not possible? Kindly Justify

Comment: First of all **Domain Controller** is an **OU** not a **Group**.Secondly when ever you create even manually an **OU** it will never ask for any kind of permissions same as in case of groups.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply,When i see the UI of Active Driectory -> Domain Controller is mentioned as Security Group- Global,So i thought it as "Security Group".Can you refer this site "http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/assign-rights-user-group-particular-ou-174853.aspx" where instead of "TestGroups" i have given "Domain Controller" in that i could access the Read and Write Permission of DOmain Controller Programmatically.Kindly clarify is the domain Controller security permission details will be stored somme where in the Active Directory Server?

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply,When i see the UI of Active Driectory -> Domain Controller is mentioned as Security Group- Global,So i thought it as "Security Group".Can you refer this site "go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/…; where instead of "TestGroups" i have given "Domain Controller" in that i could access the Read and Write Permission of DOmain Controller Programmatically.Kindly clarify is the domain Controller security permission details will be stored somme where in the Active Directory Server? My requirement is to get the Permissions of Domain controller is there is any way?